# Is a more expensive DAC guaranteed to be more efficient for audio applications?

Tags: audio, design, dac

I designed an audio circuit on a breadboard using a DAC with DIP packaging. The quality is ok except for a few artifacts I'm currently attributing to analog and digital power being too closely intertwined.

For the PCB I'm going to make, I'm deciding between 2 surface mount DACs of higher quality that appear to be similar in specs to each other but differ in price by a factor of 10. My question is what could cause the huge difference in price between the two seemingly similar devices?

The two devices have the following specs:

`MCP48FVB21    AD8300ARZ 
num bits        12            12 
num converters  1             1
Settling time   7.8us         14us
INL/DNL         1.5, 0.2      0.5, 0.5
Vdd             2.7-5.5V      2.7-5.5V
Architecture    R2R           R2R
Voltage buff    yes           yes
Comm rate       20MHz         25MHz
Latch pin       yes           yes
Size (mm)       3 x 5         5 x 6
Pins            10            10
Price           $1.38         $13.07`

Comment: YOu mean other than one is from Microchip and the other is from ANalog Devices.

Comment: Yes, should I have included that? Does one company have a process that makes it cheaper to manufacture the same type of product?

Comment: It's more about marketing strategy. Microchip is about mass production of cheap parts. AD is more about a large inventory of more exotic parts produced in batches at a premium cost.

Comment: They aren't the same product. But Analog Devices, in my very modest experience, does seem to carry a name-brand premium that goes along with a relatively good reputation in analog electronic parts (which I think they bank on.) Microchip is more of a jack of all trades and a very good business partner (in my mind anyway) and also does a credible job with good quality parts. I'd start with Microchip, personally. Also, note the differences in INL and DNL. Good DNL may mean less "artifacts." INL probably isn't so important to your application. Don't over-think the price differences, just yet.

Comment: Hmm, so I shouldn't notice a difference in quality of the two?
Makes no sense to pay 10x the price for a similar product then, maybe I'll just go with Microchip then

Comment: I noticed those were different, but those are for the LSB so its an error of about 3 out of 4095 (passed through several low pass filters and such down the line.)

Comment: It looks to me like the AD part is just old, and probably sold in low volume. Their product page recommends using AD5512A instead due to "superior performance across specifications", and this part is available for about half the price.

Comment: And the AD5512A page recommends the even-better AD5681R, which has still lower prices.

Comment: The AD prt appears to date from 1999, the uChip part from 2015. This means the latter is likely to be being built on a process an order of magnitude smaller, and therefore, an order of magnitude cheaper - cost goes with die area, 10x as many parts on the same size wafer. Note that small geometry can often impact things like noise, as I found out a few years ago, but that's unlikely to be an issue at the 12 bit level or for audio.

Comment: AD also caters to the military and as such has to manufacture on mainland USA. Microchip has no such limitation.

Comment: What is the *intended* meaning of the word "efficient" in the title???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those are not audio quality converters. PCM1789,AD1833A,AD185x series, Max5556, and CS4398 are audio quality converters.

Comment: How can I tell if they're audio quality? These mention potential applications but they don't specifically say not to use with audio.

Comment: For starters, they have only 12 bits!

Comment: Audio formats are 16, 24, 32, 40, 64 bit. 16 and 24 bit is what is currently your hardware choices for ADC/DAC applications. There are a few converter chip companies working on 32 bit converters, but the 32 and above is the logical formats that are used in software manipulation environments i.e. virtual mixers, media stream for signal processing like VST channels, ect.

Comment: @JulesC DAC that are appropriate for audio usually have an [I2S](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/I%C2%B2S) interface, not SPI. And their spec include THD+Noise, stuff like that...

Comment: @dim That's more for consumer audio, but if you just want to output some sounds and aren't too worried about CD quality etc, these will do fine. Remember 8-bit audio?

Comment: @awjlogan Sure, those are totally appropriate in a toy, for a fancy alarm, or even a telephone, talkie/walkie, etc... But OP seemed to be concerned about sound quality. In that case, I'd go for some DAC that is actually designed for hifi. They aren't much more expensive. Maybe more difficult to interface with, if you don't choose an appropriate MCU.

Comment: @Dim To be fair, the question doesn't actually say what the use is. Most "audio" DACs are very easy to use, as there are standard protocols but they tend to be streaming, and usually high rate so harder to implement yourself.

Comment: This is all very helpful, it seems I wasn't even looking at the correct DACs! So 16+ bits and generally some mention of audio applications in the data sheet. My problem was thinking all DACs were fine for audio applications, with some being better than others. And looking through them I see a lot that use I2S but I was originally looking only for SPI because of its super high transfer rate. Thank you everyone! I will familiarize myself with I2s and go on the hunt for the perfect DAC! (and accompanying ADC)

Answer (score -2):

Beware of INTERFACE DIGITAL NOISE polluting the DAC output.

Those SPI pins are *never* quiet. The MCU trash, assume 0.5 volt with 1 nanosecond Trise, will enter the SPI pins and thus enter the DAC. The trash will then explore *all* possible return paths, including your high-capacity DAC output.

Comment: Given the NOISE FLOOR is key to satisfactory audio, explain why this is not a useful answer. MCU tones, injected from the digital interfaces, will ruin the audio.